# most suitable css solution for replacing a table?

Tags: html, css, styles

From your experience, what would be the most suitable CSS solution for replacing the old unfashionable tables, with divs and styles? i am especially interested if there is a solution for replacing the table's  tags. (headers of the tables)

thank you!

Comment: This is a widespread misunderstanding: There is no fundamental problem with the `table` element. It is the right element for tabular data. It has become discouraged only where  it was abused for *layout* purposes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tableless html alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346639/tableless-html-alternative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have tabular data, then you should always use a table. There is no reason to replace it with a floating box layout.

Don't use tables for layouting your whole page.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you'll need to replace each cell() with a div.

I would then google for examples of CSS column layouts to find out which behaviour suits you best.  You can place divs in exact positions or make them relative.  Either way, if you don't know CSS you're going to have to learn it and play with it to get an idea how